# Change value of <input type> when <select> change value MySql

Tags: html, mysql, jsp, select, onchange

i need your help for a simple question:

I have a form and i need that when user select another value iin a , it will change all values of  of form.
My code is as follow:

```
<form action="updatecost.jsp" method="post" onsubmit=" return check(this)">

<tr>
    <td><i> choice cost</i></td>
    <td align="left"><select name="oldcost">

        <%
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb","user","pass");
                Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("select * FROM cost");
        String id = "";
        String year="";
        String time="";
        String cf="";
        while (rs.next()) {
            id = rs.getString("IdCost");
            year=rs.getString("year");
            time=rs.getString("time");
            cf=rs.getString("CF");
        %>

        <option value="<%=id%>"><%=year%></option>


        <%
            }
        %>
    </select></td>
    <br>
    <td><i><font color="#660033"> actual year</font></i></td>
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="year" value="<%=year%>" size="25" /></td>
    <br>
    <td><i><font color="#660033">actual cost </font></i></td>
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="cost" value="<%=cost%>" size="25" /></td>
    <br>
    <td><i><font color="#660033"> cf </font></i></td>
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="cf" value="<%=cf%>" size="25" /></td>
    <br>
    <br>
```

Comment: Looks like while you're walking the resultset you overwrite the values id/year/time/cf.  I would guess that only the last record's values are seen displayed on the page.  It might work better if you stored the records into four arrays.  And then finally, when someone selects a year from the pulldown you then replace the displayed value like id[index] by looking up one record's value as stored within the id array.

Comment: You want Ajax that hits a servlet that spits out the options...and it'd be better to put database code in servlets (or at least classes that you just call from the jsp) than spaghettified in jsps.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to save all of the results into `ArrayList<Cost> costs` then do the following:

Javascript:

```
        var ids = new Array(),
            years = new Array(),
            times = new Array(),
            cfs = new Array();

        <%
            for(Cost c: costs) {
        %>
            ids.push("<%=c.getIdCost()%>");
            years.push("<%=u.getYear()%>");
            times.push("<%=u.getTime()%>");
            cfs.push("<%=u.getCF()%>");
        <%
            }
        %>
```

Then insert an `onchange="setCost(<%=id%>);"` function into the `select` and add the JavaScript function

```
function setCost(id) {
    for(var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
        if(ids[i] == id) {
            document.getElementsByName("years")[0].value = years[i];
            document.getElementsByName("cost")[0].value = costs[i];
            document.getElementsByName("cf")[0].value = cfs[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: May i insert all the code in my .jsp file, that is where i have the form?have a .js file that comunicate with .jsp file? @nubteens

Comment: Yes, inside `<script>` tags

Comment: I got errors. Can I send you a code by mail? Here I can't. It's long answer... @nubteens

Comment: function setCost(id){
          
          alert('here I am , id : '+id);
          
          form1.newyear.value=costyear;
                 form1.submit();
                 return true;
         }
         </script>
         <tr>
          <td><i> select cost</i></td>
          <%
          String id = "ciao";
          %>
          <td align="left"><select name="oldcost"         onchange="setCost(<%=id%>);">        
          
           <%
           
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
     ......

Comment: When I pass id parameter at function setCost in the select the function don t work (alert message don t leave). if I pass a number it works @nubteens

Answer (score 0):

Try this `<select><%for(Cost c: costs) {%><option value="<%=c.getIdCost()%>" onchange="setCost(<%=c.getIdCost()%>)"><%=c.getYear()%></option><%}%></select>`

Comment: i have not the class Cost . Just a question: is it possible to connect to database in the setCost function?  @nubteens

Comment: Then what is the entity you are retrieving? Yes, as long as you use `<%%>` tags